# The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount. Truffle, privatenet

Tags: truffle, gas-limit, truffle-contract, truffle-migration

I'm developing a smart contract over private blockchain using Truffle framework.
 Developed smart contract was running well, today we have been introduced one `pure` method as per requirement. Afterwords, Truffle migrate starts giving an error:

```
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
```

However, I remove some storage variable makes it work again. As per digging issue gas limit is not an issue, smart contract deployment taking half of gas specified for a block.

Here are some FAQs:

Q: What parameters you have removed to make it work?
A: Simple address variable:

```
//address public owner;    

constructor() public {
    //owner = msg.sender;
}
```

Q: Could you please show your code?
A: I can't, due to confidentiality as well code is huge.

Q: What gas limit you have specified in truffle js file?
A: 4712388

Q: Have you tried to increase Gas limit?
A: Yes, but no luck.

**Edit: Contract structure**

```
import "./ContractB.sol";

Contract A is ContractB{

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    index = 0;
    userID = 0;
  }
}
```

---

```
import "./ContractC.sol";

Contract B is ContractC{

}
```

---

```
Contract C {

}
```

Error comes with migration of `ContractA` and new function added in `ContractB`.

Comment: Q: Did you implement all abstract methods from parent interfaces and abstract contracts?

Comment: A: I'm having 3 contracts, and I made it separated based on functionalities. There is no interface or abstract contracts, am using simple inheritance.

Comment: @Henk: updated question with contract structure

Comment: Thanks. So there are no functions without body in A, B or C?

Comment: @Henk No, not a single one.

Comment: @Henk: Resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line answer: this issue is simply resolved by increasing GAS limit in Geth.